# Windows device driver sniffing / debugging

Tags: windows, linux, io, device-driver, sniffing

I've recently bought a laptop with a touch pad that does not completely work under Linux. So I thought I might listen what data is sent to the PS2 controller (IO port 60) under Windows, and update the Linux driver accordingly. Do you know what tools I might use?

Answer (score 0):

[Perisoft Bushound](http://www.perisoft.net/bushound/index.htm) - Expensive but very useful.

Comment: Wow, US $799 per user. That *is* expensive.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yep. It's an absolute necessity for some of my work, so I got it, but you may not want to spend that much for a single task. You can try using their trial though.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific purpose I'd use some serial port monitor/sniffer software.

You may write your own tool that does the same, but that's a large amount of work. You should create a so-called file system filter driver (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968).